# How to show Toast or Confetti animation over the main page and bottom sheet in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Issues : when the bottom sheet is opened toast or Confetti animation is visible in the main page not over the bottom sheet.

[image: Bottom Sheet]

Answer (score 1):

Please try this package : it will work in case of bottom sheet also : [toast](https://pub.dev/packages/bot_toast)

2. https://pub.dev/packages/overlay_support
3. https://pub.dev/packages/toast